# Gitlab Shared Runner docker build after npm install

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-runner

I'm trying to build docker image and push to gitlab registry.

I'm using gitlab-shared runner.

There is no problems for npm install but how to build docker image on next job?

```
image: node:14.17.3

stages:
  - install
  - build


install_dependencies:
  stage: install
  tags:
    - gitlab-org-docker
  script:
    - pwd
    - npm install

build-job:
  stage: build
  image: docker
  tags:
    - gitlab-org-docker
  script:
    - echo "Compiling the code..."
    - echo "build"
    - docker build -t bmw-frontend-app .
    - docker ps
```

[image]

I had forgot about dind. dind means Docker in Docker.

I succeed like below.

```
image: docker:19.03.13

cache:
  key: ${CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG}
  paths:
  - node_modules/
  - .next/

stages:
  - build

services:
  - docker:19.03.13-dind

build-job:
  stage: build
  before_script:
    - echo docker login $DOCKER_REGISTRY --username $DOCKER_REGISTRY_USER --password-stdin
  tags:
    - gitlab-org-docker
  script:
    - echo "Compiling the code..."
    - echo "build"
    - docker build -t registry.gitlab.com/areum.lee1/bmwgs_frontend . 
    - docker login registry.gitlab.com -u $DOCKER_REGISTRY_USER -p $DOCKER_REGISTRY_PASS
    - docker push registry.gitlab.com/areum.lee1/bmwgs_frontend
```

1. I modified outer image to image: docker:19.03.12
2. append service block.

[image]

Comment: If you mention the node_modules from ```stage: install``` for ```stage: build```, you can try with **cache** (```https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/caching/```). I haven't tried with dind or shared runner but I think It can work.

Answer (score 0):

You should check out GitLab's documentation about using docker-in-docker as it has a great walkthrough; in this particular case you're missing the dind service that actually executes the docker commands, that's why you're getting the connect error.

Link: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/docker/using_docker_build.html#docker-in-docker-with-tls-enabled

Comment: Thanks I've missed about dind. But I tried to find about this on above document but I  hadn't then I uploded this question on this and I hadn't found about docker build after npm install. I think you don't have experience about npm install. Isn't it?

Comment: Sorry Matthew, I'm having a little bit of trouble understanding your English, so let me make sure I understand the question you're asking: You didn't actually mean to ask a question about `dind`, you actually meant to ask how you could run `npm install` in one job and then use the results from the `npm install` in the next job? If so, you should check out the `artifacts` keyword for your CI/CD which will save a set of files/directories from your job, and download those files into the same spot in subsequent jobs.

Comment: Thanks Patrick, I solved this problem like above. I changed image to docker from node.